# Cross-site Publishing in SharePoint Online - Possible?

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, managed-navigation, managed-metadata-service, cross-site

I have successfully configured Cross-site publishing in SharePoint 2013 on-premises environments. I say this only to demonstrate I'm somewhat familiar with the nuances of getting this working and I have done my due diligence on ensuring the obvious things are working such as content has been crawled, etc. I'm trying to do the same now in SharePoint Online but with little success.

This question is to see if anyone else has gotten cross-site publishing to actually work in SharePoint Online. This work has been done on an E3 tenant.

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Created 2 site collections: authoring and consuming. On the authoring site collection, enable the Cross-site Publishing site collection feature.
2. Created managed term set in authoring site collection.
3. Created custom list content type and site column to reference the term set created above. This is what will be used to drive the navigation on the consuming site collection.
4. Created a custom list on authoring site collection using the above custom content type and added a bunch of items.
5. Identified the list as a catalog.
6. Requested a re-index of the list.
7. Wait...for the re-index to happen... and it did.
8. On the consuming site collection, go to 'Manage Catalog Connections' and try connecting to the catalog created in the authoring site collection.
9. It's there as an available connection (its been crawled) so I connect to it and select the correct term to be the start of the navigation.
10. I selected the option to have the category and catalog item pages created automatically for me.
11. Confirmed the navigation is showing correctly on the consuming site collection.
12. When I click any of the navigation items, no results are returned in the content search web parts that are on the category pages.
13. I edited the content search webpart on the page to ensure I was getting search results back and I definitely am in the search result preview. I am using the catalog as the result source and have the 'Restrict by child and navigation terms' option selected. All items from the catalog are returning in the search result preview pane while editing the webpart.

Note: I'm using the "friendly url" option.
Example: http://mysposite.sharepoint.com/sites/dairy/milk   ...should display the items under the dairy/milk term category.

I also tried these page options:

1. a custom category page using the same page layout that was generated by the custom page
2. a custom category page with a blank webpart page layout

NONE of the pages will show any search results when clicking on any of the navigation terms. Ever.

QUESTION: have you been successful in getting cross-site publishing working in SharePoint Online?  If yes, can you suggest where I might have gone wrong in my setup/configuration?

Comment: What's the SP online plan? Enterprise E3 or above?

Comment: Enterprise E3.  I've now got it working.  I believe it had something to do with the managed property settings for the managed metadata column that was driving the navigation.  I adjusted the settings on the property and it is working now.  I am blogging a series about the setup.

Comment: Can you please send me the blog url. I have also same requirement which is failing

Comment: Here is a link to the first of my 3-part blog series on doing XSP in SharePoint Online.  https://joannecklein.com/2016/07/01/lets-play-ball-xsp-in-spo-part-i/  Please let me know if his helps you out (by replying to my blog post preferably)

Answer (score 1):

After testing I was able to show the HTML Content of the Authoring site's page by changing the Property Mappings of the Content Search Web Part. I used 'PublishingPageContentOWSHTML' as a manged property to do this.